# CSS Layout: Footer at bottom OR end of page (if further down)

Tags: html, css

I know, this kind of questions has been asked a lot, but somehow the correct answer is always eluding me...

Ok, I've got two things I want:

- A footer that's always on the bottom of the page, no matter if the content has less height than the available screen or more.
- The content above the footer should fill the rest of the screen - or use more space, if needed

The first part is quite easy, for example, [here](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx), with something like this...

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

No problem there. But how can I get the content above the `.footer` element to fill the remaining space? `height=100%;` obviously doesn't work;

Anyone got an idea how to realize a layout with...

- A fixed header
- A footer at the bottom of the screen (or below, if the content needs more height than that)
- A content that fills the available screen or uses more, if needed

(The reason is that in the end, I want a grid with flexible height that fills the screen in the content)

Comment: Have you checked this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)?

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer something more compatible to older browsers, but perhaps it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #9f0d0d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    min-height: 5%;
}

    header :first-child {
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }

article {
    top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: fixed;
}

footer {
    top: 95%;
    min-height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #9f0d0d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <article>CONTENT</article>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

Feel Free to play with this code block.